# gulp, git, php & production build

Tags: php, git, gulp

I have a application in php. I use a lots of javascript, css, fonts and other thing.

Everything is versionned with git, and I update my servers with git. My server are on the master branch, and I push everything to it to update the code on my server.

So, now I would like to upgrade my code and start using gulp with it to automatically compile javascript, use sass and generate fonts.

I do not wish to install gulp on my server in case something goes wrong, my website will be unoperationnal. So I have to be able to create a build version with the compiled files of javascript, css...  But don't want to always commit thoses files since it will cause conflict in my team everytime we change version.

What would be the best workflow to create a build version with all the compiled files and not cause any conflict in git?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my setup:

[image]

Notice the task deploy? Well, *deploy* with the parameter *--release*, releases to a different location that just plain *deploy*.

It should be as simple as deploying to different locations. In your case to different hosted folders from which you can access two different web apps. One that works, and one in development.

To your statement:

> I do not wish to install gulp on my server in case something goes
>   wrong,

You don't need gulp on your server at all whatsoever. I have gulp on my build Teamcity server, but that's about it.

Anyhow, that's what works for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm guessing that in your normal build, you still compile the js and css, but you should ignore the compiled files (with a gitignore file?). But with your deploy, how do you override the ignores files? Or do you copy all your files to a other folder that have a different gitignore file?

Comment: By the way I use TFS, not Git (unfortunately). I always ignore the "compiled files". They are merely artifacts of the build process, just like exes and dlls. Now, my deploy copies the non-compiled, non-minified, non-optimized, non-everything files to my test server where we can chase bugs and so on. My deploy --release on the other hand compiles, optimizes, minifies, concatenates, revises ... all the files to produce a single html file and a single css and a single js file which make it into the QA server

Comment: If you don't have a build server you should look into having one. It can automate so many steps for you and will add consistency and reliability to your development process. It can also maintain a version of your artifacts. Meaning that it will keep track of your compiled files and that way you know which artifacts deployed to QA or production are a result of which changeset in source control,

Comment: What exactly are the main features of a build server?

Comment: It monitors source control for commits/check-ins. It then gets the latest and greatest from source control and builds the code. Meaning all the operations I described before as well as compiling other source code like C# code. It then runs all the unit tests on our C# code, and runs all the unit tests on our font end code such as javascript. It runs lint, or lint mechanisms that enforce a coding standard in order to guarantee code quality.  continued...

Comment: It then runs code coverage analysis to see how much of the code is tested by the unit tests.If the last commit/check-in broke the build, meaning it broke the system or part of it, It then notifies the developer responsible for the disaster so that they can go and fix it., commit the fix and kick start the process again. If all goes well, and after other checks, it deploys the artifacts, meaning the result of the build to the test server, or QA server.

Comment: I find it hard to maintain quality and tractability without a build server. And the build server should follow your build process described by the build section of your development process. Hope that helps.